# Using bundle vs gem for managing gems?

Tags: rubygems

I am new to Ruby, and it seems like people use both `gem` as well as `bundle` on the command line to install, update, remove, and manage gems. Are RubyGems and Bundler interchangeable for gem management? I cannot tell the difference between `gem install` and `bundle install`, for instance.

Answer (score 10):

`gem install` installs the specified gem.

e.g., `gem install <gem_name>`

`bundle install` reads the `Gemfile` and installs all the gems mentioned in `Gemfile`

Comment: But what is the difference between installing with `gem` and installing with `bundle` ? I'm sorry if I misunderstood you, but it sounded like you said they both install gems, except that `bundle` reads from the Gemfile.